# How to change an entire div element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio, authentication

I'm building a site with visual studio for web for a school project and I did a user login system. so in my site I have on the top bar a place to put your username your password and to press log in. now I want that when the user will press the log in button all of this will changed to "welcome back" while his session is activated. so I just need to know how can I changed a div element (that has all the login things) to another div that display text.
Thanks for answering.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 1):

You should have 2 divs.

First one is the "login-bar" div, this one should be visible. And the second one is the "welcome-back-bar" div which should be hidden.

When the user log in, you should hide the "login-bar" div and show the "welcome-back-bar" div.

This way it will look like that the "login-bar" div is replaced by the "welcome-back-bar" div.

```
$(function(){
    $("#login-button").click(function(){
        $("#login-bar").addClass("hidden");
        $("#welcome-back-bar").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

See this
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SxjS/)